# ajax jquery dataTable does not go to the specified actionMethod

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am using jQuery dataTable with asp.net MVC.

**my actionMethod code is :**

```
    public ActionResult getEmployeesInfo(JQueryDataTableParams param) {
      EmployeeBL obj_EmployeeBL = new EmployeeBL();
      var result = obj_EmployeeBL.getEmployeesData(param);

      return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      //    return PartialView("_EmployeesList", Json( result,
      //        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
    }
```

**BL and DAL is:**

```
public string getEmployeesData(JQueryDataTableParams param) {
  using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conne"].ConnectionString)) {
    List < EmployeeDataViewModel > lst_Employees = new List < EmployeeDataViewModel > ();
    int filteredCount = 0;
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spGetEmployees", conn)) {
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      //  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentCulture", currentCultuer);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayLength", param.iDisplayLength);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayStart", param.iDisplayStart);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortCol", param.iSortCol_0);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortDir", param.sSortDir_0);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", param.sSearch);

      conn.Open();

      command.CommandTimeout = 500;
      SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
      while (rdr.Read()) {
        EmployeeDataViewModel emp = new EmployeeDataViewModel();

        filteredCount = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["TotalCount"]);

        emp.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["EmployeeId"]);
        emp.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
        emp.Level_1Name = rdr["level1"].ToString();
        emp.Level_2Name = rdr["level2"].ToString();
        emp.Level_3Name = rdr["level3"].ToString();
        emp.Level_4Name = rdr["level4"].ToString();
        emp.Level_5Name = rdr["level5"].ToString();
        emp.RankName = rdr["RankNO"].ToString();
        if (rdr["Rank"] != DBNull.Value) {
          emp.Rank = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Rank"]);
        }
        emp.EmployeeTypeName = (rdr["EmployeeType"] != DBNull.Value) ? rdr["EmployeeType"].ToString() : "-";
        lst_Employees.Add(emp);
      }

      var result = new {
        // sEcho = param.sEcho,
        iTotalRecords = GetEmployeeTotalCount(),
          iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredCount,
          data = lst_Employees
      };

      JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      return js.Serialize(result);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#EmployeesDataTable').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "columns": [
  { 'data': 'EmployeeId' },
  { 'data': 'Name' },
  { 'data': 'Level_1Name' },
  { 'data': 'Level_2Name' },
  { 'data': 'Level_3Name' },
  { 'data': 'Level_4Name' },
  { 'data': 'Level_5Name' },
  { 'data': 'RankName' },
  { 'data': 'Rank' },
  { 'data': 'EmployeeTypeName' }
   ],
"bServerSide": true,
"ajax": {
       "url":'@Url.Action("getEmployeesInfo","Emp_Employee")',
       "dataSrc": ""
          }
});
});
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover" id="EmployeesDataTable">
<thead>
  <tr class="">
    <th>@Resource.ID</th>
    <th>@Resource.EmployeeName</th>
    <th>@Resource.FirstLevel</th>
    <th>@Resource.SecondLevel</th>
    <th>@Resource.ThirdLevel</th>
    <th>@Resource.FourthLevel</th>
    <th>@Resource.FifthLevel</th>
    <th>@Resource.RankNumber</th>
    <th>@Resource.Rank</th>
    <th>@Resource.EmpType</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

the problem is my code does not go to the url inside ajax. and then the following alert box is appear

`DataTables` warning `(table id = 'EmployeesDataTable'):` `DataTables` warning: `JSON` data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a `JSON` formatting error.

I think my dataTable did not understand what is ajax mean.

Comment: returning the result as string

Answer (score 0):

Here a string is passed to Json() method instead return result as anonymous object

```
public ActionResult getEmployeesInfo(JQueryDataTableParams param) {
      EmployeeBL obj_EmployeeBL = new EmployeeBL();
       var result = obj_EmployeeBL.getEmployeesData(param);

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I changed the code to work with object

```
  public object getEmployeesData(JQueryDataTableParams param) {
  using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conne"].ConnectionString)) {
    List < EmployeeDataViewModel > lst_Employees = new List < EmployeeDataViewModel > ();
    int filteredCount = 0;
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spGetEmployees", conn)) {
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      //  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentCulture", currentCultuer);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayLength", param.iDisplayLength);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayStart", param.iDisplayStart);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortCol", param.iSortCol_0);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortDir", param.sSortDir_0);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", param.sSearch);

      conn.Open();

      command.CommandTimeout = 500;
      SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
      while (rdr.Read()) {
        EmployeeDataViewModel emp = new EmployeeDataViewModel();

        filteredCount = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["TotalCount"]);

        emp.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["EmployeeId"]);
        emp.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
        emp.Level_1Name = rdr["level1"].ToString();
        emp.Level_2Name = rdr["level2"].ToString();
        emp.Level_3Name = rdr["level3"].ToString();
        emp.Level_4Name = rdr["level4"].ToString();
        emp.Level_5Name = rdr["level5"].ToString();
        emp.RankName = rdr["RankNO"].ToString();
        if (rdr["Rank"] != DBNull.Value) {
          emp.Rank = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Rank"]);
        }
        emp.EmployeeTypeName = (rdr["EmployeeType"] != DBNull.Value) ? rdr["EmployeeType"].ToString() : "-";
        lst_Employees.Add(emp);
      }

      var result = new {
        // sEcho = param.sEcho,
        iTotalRecords = GetEmployeeTotalCount(),
          iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredCount,
          data = lst_Employees
      };

      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ...
but it still not working .
When i put a debug point to getEmployeesInfo ActionResult  the debugger did not go to this function ,and same error appear 

"DataTables warning (table id = 'EmployeesDataTable'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error."

Comment: Goto Chrome Dev tools in the network what is the response you are getting for the request

Comment: Thanks all, I solved this issue you can see my answer above :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is:
 1. update  jquery.dataTables.min.js to a new version so that my datatable understood what "ajax" means. By inserting the following to the LayOut.cshtml:

```js
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
```

2. modify "getEmployeesInfo" Action to the following:

   ```
    public ActionResult getEmployeesInfo()
   {
       string search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0];
       string draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw")[0];
       string order = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]")[0];
       string orderDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]")[0];
       int startRec = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("start")[0]);
       int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("length")[0]);
       EmployeeBL obj_EmployeeBL = new EmployeeBL();
       var employeeDataViewModel = obj_EmployeeBL.getEmployeesData(draw,search, order,orderDir, startRec, pageSize);
       int recordsTotal = employeeDataViewModel.TotalCount;
       int recordsFiltered = employeeDataViewModel.filteredCount;

       var data = employeeDataViewModel.lst_employeeData;
       var result = this.Json(new { draw = Convert.ToInt32(draw), recordsTotal = recordsTotal, recordsFiltered = recordsFiltered, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


       return result;

   }
   ```

   3. Modify "getEmployeesData" function as following:

      public EmployeeDataViewModel getEmployeesData(string draw,string search, string order, string orderDir,int startRec, int pageSize)
      {
          using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ATASSqlCon"].ConnectionString))
          {
              EmployeeDataViewModel obj_EmployeeDataViewModel = new EmployeeDataViewModel();
              obj_EmployeeDataViewModel.lst_employeeData = new List();
              int filteredCount = 0;
              using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spGetEmployees", conn))
              {
                  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      ```
              command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayLength",pageSize);
              command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayStart",startRec);
              command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortCol",Convert.ToInt32(order));
              command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortDir", orderDir);
              command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", search);

              conn.Open();

              command.CommandTimeout = 500;
              SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
              while (rdr.Read())
              {
                  EmployeeDataModel emp = new EmployeeDataModel();

                  filteredCount = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["TotalCount"]);

                  emp.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt64(rdr["EmployeeId"]);
                  emp.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                  emp.Level_1Name = rdr["level1"].ToString();
                  emp.Level_2Name = rdr["level2"].ToString();
                  emp.Level_3Name = rdr["level3"].ToString();
                  emp.Level_4Name = rdr["level4"].ToString();
                  emp.Level_5Name = rdr["level5"].ToString();
                  emp.RankName = rdr["RankNO"].ToString();
                  if (rdr["Rank"] != DBNull.Value)
                  {
                      emp.Rank = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Rank"]);
                  }
                  emp.EmployeeTypeName = (rdr["EmployeeType"] != DBNull.Value) ? rdr["EmployeeType"].ToString() : "-";



                  obj_EmployeeDataViewModel.lst_employeeData.Add(emp);
              }
              obj_EmployeeDataViewModel.TotalCount = GetEmployeeTotalCount();
              obj_EmployeeDataViewModel.filteredCount = filteredCount;



              return obj_EmployeeDataViewModel;
          }
      }
      ```

      }
   4. Modify Script as following:

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#EmployeesDataTable').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [
              {
                  "width": "5%",
                  "targets": [0]
              },
              {
                  "className": "text-center custom-middle-align",
                  "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
              }, ],
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":
          {
              "url": "/Emp_Employee/getEmployeesInfo",
              "type": "POST",
              "dataType": "JSON"
          },
            "columns": [
              {
                  "data": "EmployeeId"
              },
              {
                  "data": "Name"
              },
               {
                   "data": "Level_1Name"
               },
              {
                  "data": "Level_2Name"
              },
              {
                  "data": "Level_3Name"
              },
              {
                  "data": "Level_4Name"
              },
              {
                  "data": "Level_5Name"
              },
              {
                  "data": "RankName"
              },
            {
                "data": "Rank"
            },
            {
                "data": "EmployeeTypeName"
            }]
        });
    });
```